# HTML: Correct way to layout the form elements?

Tags: html

This is how I usually layout the form elements in the same row:

```html
<div style="vertical-align: middle">
   Field: <input id="Text3" type="text" /><input id="Button3" type="button" 
      value="button" />
</div>
```

However, it doesn't look very good, the button and the input-text don't align well (even though I've wrapped them with a vertical-align `DIV`).

Is there anything that can be done to make it look better (like some CSSing)?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do what you are asking and there is no single correct answer. You could use a framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) to handle all the CSS for you, or write your own. You should also modify the structure of the HTML itself and include proper `<label...` tags etc

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can style your boxes many ways, along with your button. Just look up some CSS and you are on your way. Also I would use a separate style sheet instead of the inline CSS that you have right now.

Comment: how to ensure the text box to have the same height as the button?

Comment: @im_chc just honestly you're probably not going to be able to make it exactly the same size across all browsers. But with some CSS you can get it pretty close. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgxxpQ

Comment: +1 for the padding setting, just the kind of stuff I'm looking for, as AFAIK I saw it in most of the sites I've been